# iPhone: increasing size of view frame in a UItabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I currently have a UITabBarController defined, **with the tab bar moved a few pixels down to make it thinner**:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame=CGRectMake(0,self.window.bounds.size.height-38.5,self.window.bounds.size.width,50);

[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

I then have a UIViewController object assigned to the first tab using:

```
    Home *home = [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nHome = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home]; 
nHome.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]; 
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nHome,nil]];
```

As a result, there is a thin sliver of space between the tabbarcontroller and the view. Can someone please tell me how I can get rid of this space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you moved the tabbar down, you have to move the view down as well.

Comment: what method/object frame do i need to access to do this?